# Fuzzy search in Asset Library

Tags: assets, search

Has anyone out there found a way to do a fuzzy search in the Asset Library? Currently, search only seems to return results that match the exact search query. Any help or plugin link is greatly apprecitated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a fuzzy search using the `*` character.  See [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) for a list of supported syntaxes.

**Update:**
As of [Craft 2.5](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2750), you can enable [fuzzy](https://craftcms.com/help/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) searching by default.

Comment: Not perfect, since it requires some client training...but good enough!