# Implementing search with Ajax

Tags: search

What is the best way to implement a typeahead search in Craft. I looked at using ElementAPI to do something similar at this example but it doesn't seem to allow me to wildcard search

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/search-form

Here's an example of the endpoints I have configured:

I have one entry with a title of "test" when I call the API doing

When I call `/entries/te` its returns 0 results. When I call `/entries/test` it returns 1 result.

```
<?php

namespace Craft;
return [
    'endpoints' => [

        'entries/<search:\w+>' => function($search) {
            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => ['title' => $search]
            ];
        }

    ]
];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "wildcard search?" What have you tried, already, within your `criteria` block in the ElementAPI configuration?

Comment: Essentially,  I want to be able to search for entries using any syntaxes mention here https://craftcms.com/docs/searching. When I use the ElementAPI is only returns the results when using the exact word.

Comment: Can you edit the original question and share the relevant portion of your Element API config where you're trying to perform the search?

Comment: Ahh, not so much element-api related, but basically this answer is what you're looking for I'm guessing? http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5477/57

Comment: @BradBell this is exactly what I would like to do but throught the ElementAPI so  can return JSON

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable fuzzy searching globally (across the entire Craft install - CP, front-end, ElementAPI, etc.), you can use the [defaultSearchTerms](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultSearchTermOptions) config setting.

You can also just do it programmatically from the ElementAPI plugin with something like:

Suffix wildcard:

```
'criteria' => ['title' => $search ~ '*']
```

Prefix wildcard:

```
'criteria' => ['title' => '*' ~ $search]
```

Both sides:

```
'criteria' => ['title' => '*' ~ $search ~ '*']
```

Or you can use any of the other search syntaxes listed on the [search docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) page.